# How to create a dependency docker container separate from an official docker image?

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-12

I’m struggling to install some **python dependencies** separate from an official **docker image** `(Odoo:12.0)`. I’m trying to learn docker but I’m not sure what to do in this case. I’ve tried:

1. Rebuilding the image adding the dependencies in the Dockerfile
   (Somehow a bunch of dependencies fail to install via this method…)
2. Manually entering the docker container and downloading the dependencies there (Odoo doesn’t recognize the dependencies and
   tells me the dependency is missing.)

I’ve read that one could make a sort of separate volume with those extra dependencies but I haven’t achieved much. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Cheers

Comment: Please provide your `Dockerfile` so that anyone can help you.

Comment: Manually installing software in a running container is almost never correct; anything you do this way will get lost as soon as you exit and delete the container.  Similarly, you generally shouldn't keep code or dependencies in volumes, they should be built into the image.  Building a derived image running something like `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` is usually right; what specific problem are you running into?